# Add comment to cell

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I have to insert comment to existing Excel file, 
using `OleDb` connection.

Here is my Insert method, How to add Excel comments to specific cell?

```
private static string BuildInsertCommand(DataTable dataTable, int rowIndex)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendFormat("INSERT INTO [{0}$](", BuildExcelSheetName(dataTable));
    for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
        sb.Append("F"+(i+1)+",");
    sb = sb.Replace(',', ')', sb.ToString().LastIndexOf(','), 1);
    sb.Append("VALUES (");
    foreach (DataColumn col in dataTable.Columns)
    {
        string type = col.DataType.ToString();
        string strToInsert = String.Empty;
        strToInsert = dataTable.Rows[rowIndex][col].ToString().Replace("'", "''");
        sb.AppendFormat("'{0}',", strToInsert);
    }
    sb = sb.Replace(',', ')', sb.ToString().LastIndexOf(','), 1);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Sadly, you cannot add comments to cells using OLEDB. You can only use Excel Interop. Incidentally May I suggest you investigate OLE Command parameters rathern than building an SQL statement in this manner.

Comment: thanks for quickly answare! I read in some post I can use EPPlus or ExcelLibrary, but my question is is it possible to use those external libraries and publish the MVC application withoutt depentencies on server installations?

Comment: EPPlus does not require Excel.  I think that's one of the main advantages of it.  It functions a lot like interop, only without the COM dependency.

Comment: OK, and what about NOPI?

Comment: Your question has become "which library should I use" which is off-topic for SO.  If you want to know if NPOI supports adding comments, read its documentation or ask a question on its board.